# Java Chess: IsInCheck() Method not Functioning Properly

Tags: java

I'm writing a chess game in Java have set it up with a Board class that has a 2d array of Square objects. Each square has a height and width (between 0 and 7 inclusive).

I'm writing a method in my Board class that determines whether the passed in player is in check (given the current state of the board).

```
public boolean isInCheck(Player candidatePlayer) {

        String candidateColor = candidatePlayer.getColor();

        //get opposite color of candidatePlayer
        String oppositeColor = candidateColor.equals("w") ? "b" : "w";

        //loop through squares
        for (int i = 0; i < myBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myBoard[i].length; j++) {
                //if current square not empty

                if (! myBoard[i][j].isEmpty()) {

                    //if piece at current square is opposite color of candidate player
                    if (myBoard[i][j].getPiece().getColor().equals(oppositeColor)) {
                        ArrayList<Square> squares = myBoard[i][j].getPiece().getLegalDestinationSquares(myBoard[i][j]);

                        //if piece's current legal squares moves contains square of candidatePlayer's king
                        if (candidateColor.equals("w")) {

                            if (squares.contains(whiteKingSquare)) {
                                    return true;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (squares.contains(blackKingSquare)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I've set up the following board position:

```
bR  bKn bB  bP  bK  bP  bP  bR  
bP  bP       bP     bP  --  bP  bP  bP  
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  
--  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  
wP  wP  wP  wP  wQ  wP  wP  wP  
wR  wKn wB  wQ  wK  wB  wKn wR
```

The black king is currently in check.  However, when I run my isInCheckmate(player) method, it returns false.  It claims that the black king can move one square down.

Here's my code:

```
public boolean isCheckmated(Player candidatePlayer, Player other) {
    //if candidate player currently in check
    if (isInCheck(candidatePlayer)) {
        //loop through all squares
        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
                Square current = myBoard[i][j];
                //if current square has one of candidatePlayer's pieces
                if (current != null) {
                    if (current.getPiece().getColor().equals(candidatePlayer.getColor())) {
                        ArrayList<Square> squares = current.getPiece().getLegalDestinationSquares(current);
                        //loop through all of that piece's moves
                        for (Square square : squares) {
                            //if player can make that move and not in check
                            if (canMovePiece(current, square, candidatePlayer, other)) {
                                System.out.println("escape square is at " + square.getHeight() + " " + square.getWidth());
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

UPDATE: Including code for canMovePiece here:

```
public boolean canMovePiece(Square start, Square end, Player player1, Player player2) {

        //squares are non-null
        if (start != null && end != null) {

            //get color of moving player
            String movingPlayerColor = start.getPiece().getColor();
            Player movingPlayer = player1.getColor().equals(movingPlayerColor) ? player1 : player2;

            //squares are valid
            if (isValidSquare(start.getHeight(), start.getWidth()) && isValidSquare(end.getHeight(), end.getWidth())) {
                //if there is a piece at start square and ending square isn't of same color
                if (start.getPiece() != null) {
                    //if end square has a piece on it, must be of different color (or end square is empty)
                    if (end.getPiece() != null && ! end.getPiece().getColor().equals(movingPlayerColor) || end.getPiece() == null)
                        //if piece at start can move to square at end
                        if (start.getPiece().getLegalDestinationSquares(start).contains(end)) {

                            //store captured piece so we can undo move later
                            Piece captured = end.getPiece();
                            //make move
                            movePiece(start, end);
                            boolean playerInCheck = isInCheck(movingPlayer);

                            //if player who made move not in check
                            if (! playerInCheck) {
                                //undo move
                                movePiece(end, start);
                                if (captured != null) {
                                    end.setPiece(captured);
                                }
                                //return true
                                return true;
                            }

                            //else (player who made move is in check)
                            else {
                                //undo move
                                movePiece(end, start);
                                if (captured != null) {
                                    end.setPiece(captured);
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

I still can't figure out why my code thinks the king is out of check if it moves a square down (where it's still in check by the white queen).

Any help much appreciated!
-Mariogs

Comment: what does canMovePiece do?

Comment: You might want to show the code for your `canMovePiece` method, but would suggest that in that method, you check for `isInCheck` if not already, to ensure that it is indeed not listed as a valid move.

Comment: It's not about the question, but you should probably use a Boolean instead of a string for the color.

Comment: @AmirAfghani added requested code.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanJ added requested code

Comment: Please check/print out/update the result of `getLegalDestinationSquares()`.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: add as much code as you can, otherwise people need to assume stuff.  Square, Player, Piece, getLegalDestinationSquares()...